# C# XNA equivalent of Java's PriorityQueue with Comparator?

Tags: c#, java, xna, priority-queue, comparator

I'm implementing Dijkstra's on a board of tiles. I want to store all the tiles in a Priority Queue, sorted by their distance from the starting location. In Java, this would be something like:

`Queue<Point> pq = new PriorityQueue<Point>(new Comparator() { /* sort by distance from start */ });`

What would the equivalent by in C# XNA? C# has a `PriorityQueue` class, but that only works for `IComparable` objects, which `Point` objects are not.

Comment: Why not create an object derived from `Point` that implements `IComparable` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can't derive from the struct Point, you could do a minimal implementation of a IComparable ComparablePoint class, with a Point as a composite member.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easy solution is to implement your own class for storing a node and make it comparable (by implementing the IComparable interface).